# Can find the download file in azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I'm trying to use azure pipeline to upload certificate and binding the app service.
First I use a DEV-stage,all works well.Currently I have to create a new stage for QUAL env.Just clone a new stage from DEV-stage and update the variables,but we run the pipeline can not find the certificate(file) I uploaded.
My download task is:

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download ***.**.com Certificate for API App'
  inputs:
    secureFile: dev.pfx
```

and then use a azure powershell task，but in my script such error happens:

```
Certificate does not exist at path D:\a\_temp/
```

It seems can not find the download file in the agent.
[image]

Uploaded task:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@3
  displayName: 'Upload Certificate to API app and Bind Domain'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure: CDA NextGen DEV'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CdaApi-ArmTemplates/ArmTemplates/InstallSSLAndCustomDomain.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupName) -AppServiceName $(ApiSiteName) -CustomDomains $(ApiHostName) -CertificatePassword $(Password) -CertificateFileName $(CertificateFileName)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

power shell script:

```
$CertificateFilePath = $env:AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY + "/" +  $CertificateFileName

$ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion 2014-11-01

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($CertificateFilePath)) 
{
    Write-Host ("Certificate found at {0}" -f $CertificateFilePath)
}
else 
{
    Write-Error ("Certificate does not exist at path {0}" -f $CertificateFilePath)
    throw
}
```

How to check it?

Comment: How do you define your azure powershell task to upload this certificate? Maybe the complete YAML would be much clear?

Comment: I just use a power shell script and copy the YAML to the question

Comment: So you defined InstallSSLAndCustomDomain.ps1 to upload the secure file, and how do you configured the secure file path in that powershell script? Also, are you using Hosted ubuntu agent?

Comment: I copied some scripts above.No,I'm using windows agent

Comment: I added a script just now and list the files in path $(Agent.TempDirectory),I can get the file I uploaded.But in my ps files got the error there.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

Based on your comment the files has been exists there. Also, combine your powershell script and your error message.

Since you just share the part of your YAML, I could not know how do you define variables. Please ensure your `CertificateFileName` variable has been stored and passed to powershell successfully.

Because, the complete file name should be displayed in your powershell error message even it does not exists in path.

---

In fact, it is very easy to cause some issue after you change the agent environment used.

After the `Download secure file` executed, it will generated one environment variable which name is `secureFilePath`. You just need set is as output variable and use it directly in your powershell script.

Little changes on your YAML and powershell script:

**YAML:**

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download ***.**.com Certificate for API App'
  inputs:
    secureFile: dev.pfx
  name: Path

- task: AzurePowerShell@3
  displayName: 'Upload Certificate to API app and Bind Domain'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure: CDA NextGen DEV'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CdaApi-ArmTemplates/ArmTemplates/InstallSSLAndCustomDomain.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupName) -AppServiceName $(ApiSiteName) -CustomDomains $(ApiHostName) -CertificatePassword $(Password) -CertificateFileName $(CertificateFileName) -SecureFilePath $(Path.secureFilePath)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

**Powershell:**

```
$CertificateFilePath = $SecureFilePath

$ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ApiVersion 2014-11-01

if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($CertificateFilePath)) 
{
    Write-Host ("Certificate found at {0}" -f $CertificateFilePath)
}
else 
{
    Write-Error ("Certificate does not exist at path {0}" -f $CertificateFilePath)
    throw
}
```

Comment: I mean the same agent and same scripts

Comment: @KevinYANG, Confusing on it. Because in Ubuntu, `/` is the available path symbol, but not in windows agent.

Comment: Yes,me too.I just updated the script but met the same error.

Comment: @KevinYANG. I updated the reply based on your more detailed info shared, you can have a check by yourself. Because you did not share how do you configure the variable in your YAML. Just do troubleshooting way by checking whether you could get the variable `CertificateFileName` value successfully.

Comment: Yes,thanks.I guess the issue not from the path problem.It is about the variables.I have five variables in the task ScriptArguments.`cert_pass_cda-qual.schindler.com` is the fourth one comes from variable groups.It seems that it is treated as a undefined one,so the fifth one returns null.

Comment: @KevinYANG. Yep. Even file does not exists in that path, he name should also displayed in your error message. Because it is the value you passed. Now it disappeared. So I guess the value does not be got successfully. Forgive my previous judgement since I am not too familiar on your complete work logic.

Comment: @KevinYANG, why not use my second suggestion? Calling the environment variable that the task generated automatically.

Comment: Yes,It's a good idea,I will have a try later.But first I want to know why I can not get the value from variable group here?

Comment: @KevinYANG, yeah! Of course. Looking forward to your good news shared.

Comment: Here I got a strange issue,that is why these things happen.I have a variable group which are `password`,`cert_pass_cda-qual.companyname.com` .In dev stage I could use password as my privatekey password.In qual stage I use another one.This kind of name can be added into group but can not use in Script Arguments.Do you know something about this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210280/discussion-between-merlin-liang-msft-and-kevin-yang).