# Cannot find the path of downloaded file in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am trying to download certificate file in azure pipelines. I have declared it as a download secureFile task in one of yaml files of my pipeline.

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
name: certificateFileName
displayName: 'Download file Operation'
inputs:
  secureFile: mycert.crt
```

I also have another task which is the PowerShell script say Install.ps1. This script tries to import the certificate using Import-Certificate function.

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath "$(certificateFileName.secureFilePath)" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\Root"
```

I am getting an error as `ObjectNotFound` when trying to use `$(certificateFileName.secureFilePath)` within the function.
I also tried using `$(Agent.TempDirectory)` to get the path of downloaded File as suggested by the Microsoft docs. This also results in `ObjectNotFound` error.

According to this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843088/can-find-the-download-file-in-azure-pipeline#:%7E:text=In%20fact%2C%20it%20is%20very%20easy%20to%20cause,and%20use%20it%20directly%20in%20your%20powershell%20script.), it says that the path gets stored by default in `$secureFilePath` environment variable. I also tried to use this variable directly into my Import-Certificate function, but it seems the variable is empty.

What to do in this case? How do I check if download task is correctly downloading and storing the filepath?
Just a sidenote, this pipeline also has a variables.yaml declared to define variables to be used across the entire pipeline tasks.

Comment: Are these two steps in the same job, or are they in different jobs?

Comment: They are in the same job.

Answer (score 0):

First help to confirm whether these two steps are in the same job of your Azure Pipeline.

If so, you could add a PowerShell task to check the file path of this secure file on the agent.

```
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: certificateFileName
  displayName: 'Download secure file'
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'mycert.crt'

- powershell: 'echo $(certificateFileName.secureFilePath)'
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @Kim Cu-MSFT yes these two steps are in the same job. I somehow believe that my Install powershell task is not getting my filepath. Is there anyway I can pass this variable $(certtificateFileName.secureFilePath) ?